# Endless nesting/referral in javascript objects

Tags: javascript

I often notice something that I can't think -or find online- an explanation for. Often when I'm logging an object (or a DOM element, function instance, etc. displayed as an object), I see that  the object has (a reference to) itself nested within it. And not just once.

The following is an example from a ReactJS component instance:

[image]

You can see here that the 'Consumer' (instance) object refers to itself endlessly, nesting all the way down to the core of the Earth, it seems. Although I don't have the patience to click literally hundreds of times to see if this really doesn't have an end to it. P.S. this doesn't seem to be exclusive to just React.

I'm wondering: what's the point of this, and is it a javascript thing or is this just what the devtools itself does?

Comment: circular references are the norm with javascript ... window.window.window .... self.self.self ... a top level windows parent.parent.parent ... etc

Comment: That's just how the object is structured. It's not something your browser / devtools does. As for why it's done, that completely depends on the implementation

Comment: There is nothing that makes this a must, or common practice in JavaScript. JS allows it to happen but it is down to library implementations on how they architecture their objects. Iv'e not seen this with native objects, but that doesn't mean they don't exist!

EDIT: Technically above isn't a circular reference is it? Its a hierarchical structure with different instances of the same class?

Comment: @ste2425 I wouldn't call it a circular reference, no, at least not by what this appears like. TBH that would make more sense to me as opposed to what's happening here..
Or maybe many nested circular references..

Comment: @poepje my mistake, i read `endless` nesting and inferred from that circular, otherwise nothing is endless :)

Comment: @Cerbrus Could you elaborate? I don't think this is a matter of certain implementations doing this on purpose. It seems more that it happens within javascript either way, at least with certain structures.

Comment: @ste2425 Gotcha. But then I wonder, how deep does this repetition go..

Comment: If a object references itself, you have an infinitely nested object: `const a  = {}; a.a = a;`. `a` can infinitely reference to itself.

Comment: It goes as deep as the implementor wants. It has nothing to do with JS enforcing this. They are not the same objects in your example. They happen to be the same shape / instance. I think the above is representing a series of components that are nested within each other in their DOM hierarchy. They will only be as nested as far as their hierarchy goes. If it was only component A within component B then there would only be two.

Comment: @ste2425: No, that _is_ an object referring to itself.

Comment: @Cerbrus then it *is* circular no?

Comment: _"Recursive"_ seems like a more accurate term.

Comment: (Just to clarify the confusion i think I'm seeing here..) I'm the one who said I thought it isn't circular, but it _is_ indeed if the object does reference itself, yeah. That said, a single instance of component A inside B is what is rendered here, there's no actual repetition. Except in what is being logged.

Comment: @Cerbrus It's not quite recursive since it's not functionally circular. Rather, it's value-ly circular - it's circular because it contains a reference to itself. Not that it infinitely creates a scope with itself (like Lisp S-Expressions for example). There is little difference in theory but a huge difference in practice (implementation). In theory all looping structure are equivalently recursive because it is possible to transform one to the other. In practice the mechanism is different